# Thunderbird + Lightning : link emails thread to calendar event

Tags: email, thunderbird, calendar

In Thunderbird, you can convert an email to an event, but the link "email to event" is unidirectional and at the creation time.

Is there any way/plugin available to link an email thread to an event so that one could find the thread from the event in the calendar view, and find the event from the emails thread ?

Comment: You can do that with ReminderFox, which has its own calendar that can replace Lightning (it's a very full-featured application).  You can find it [here](https://addons.mozilla.org/en-US/thunderbird/addon/reminderfox/).  I posted information about it in response to a different requirement a few years ago in [this answer](https://superuser.com/a/1133121/364367).  The documentation is [here](http://www.reminderfox.org/documentation/).  It previously also worked with Firefox, but the developers didn't have the time for a total rewrite to work with Quantum; that doesn't affect Thunderbird, though.

Comment: Thanks ! ReminderFox seems a bit overkill though, and I need Lightning for compatibility with other extensions.