# Categorizing and re-categorizing appointments in Thunderbird

Tags: thunderbird, calendar

In Thunderbird, or rather in the Lightning Calendar Add-On, how best to categorize different types of appointments, e.g. for "work" and "private", or more fine-grained than that?

- Obviously, there is the "Categories" feature, but it seems like I can only assign categories to appointments that I created myself, but not categorize appointments that I receive from others, neither when I chose to accept them nor afterwards.
- I can create different local calendars for different types of appointments and assign each appointment I create *or* receive to one of those calendars; however, once assigned, I can not easily change the calendar the appointment belongs to.<sup>1</sup>

Is there any other/better way, maybe using an additional add-on, or am I missing something obvious?

---

<sup>1)</sup> I can change the calendar for appointments I created, but it will then also send an update to all other participants, which does not make any sense. Even if I click Close -> Save it will send a cancellation (!) of the original appointment. And as with categories, once accepted there seems not to be a way to change the calendar for appointments I got invited to by others.

Comment: Yeah, one shortcoming of Thunderbird is that you can't edit calendar events sent by someone else.  If I need to do that, I sometimes resort to just creating my own entry.  Several years ago, I discovered Reminderfox (see [Thunderbird reminder alarms](https://superuser.com/a/1133121/364367)).  They gave up on supporting Firefox when Mozilla changed requirements with Quantum, and it looks like the link in that answer no longer exists.  But they still support Thunderbird and it is available as an add-on: https://addons.thunderbird.net/en-US/thunderbird/addon/reminderfox/.  (cont'd)

Comment: I don't currently have it installed, so I can't explore whether the current version would be a solution for you (when I used it, you could manage categories and other things on anything).  There might also be other add-ons that would let you edit events sent by others directly in Lightning.

Comment: Bummer.  Just updated that answer.  Reminderfox would be a short-lived solution.  The developers are throwing in the towel with TB v65.